# MySQL Trigger that writes to multiples tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a trigger that I cannot get to work properly.

I have at table called _WorkOrderDump where data is input via a form. There is a trigger on this table that inserts some of the data into a table called _RefTable. The second part of this trigger is to insert some of the data into another table called __XClient.

I cannot get the second insert into the __XClient table to work, it does not insert any data into this table. The first part of the trigger inserting into Ref table is however working perfectly.

What is wrong with my query?

Thanks for any help provided!

```
CREATE TRIGGER WorkOrderTrigger

AFTER INSERT on _WorkOrderDump

BEGIN

Declare EntryDate DATETIME;
Declare RefIDDump INT;

SET EntryDate = CURDATE();
Set RefIDDump = LAST_INSERT_ID();


CASE WHEN (EntryDate) > 0
    THEN INSERT INTO `_RefTable`( `WOID`, `ClientID`, `ProjectScope`, `ProjectID`, `ClientRef`, `SiteID`, `SiteName`, `RegionID`, `SiteAddressLine`, `SiteAddressSuburb`, `SiteAddressState`, `SiteAddressPostcode`, `SiteAddressCountry`, `SiteContactName`, `SiteContactMobile`, `SiteContactPhone`, `SiteContactEmail`, `RefEntryDate`, `CreatedBY`)
    VALUES
    ( new.WOID, new.ClientID, new.ProjectScope, new.ProjectID, new.ClientRef, new.SiteID, new.SiteName, new.RegionID, new.SiteAddressLine, new.SiteAddressSuburb, new.SiteAddressState, new.SiteAddressPostcode, new.SiteAddressCountry, new.SiteContactName, new.SiteContactMobile, new.SiteContactPhone, new.SiteContactEmail, EntryDate, new.CreatedBY);


    WHEN (new.ClientID) = 1
    THEN INSERT INTO `__XClient`( `RefID`, `ITContactName`, `ITContactPhone`, `ITContactEmail`, `XScope32`, `XScope43`, `XScopeMediaPlayer`, `XScopeInstallDate`, `XScopeInstallTime`, `XScopeComments`)
    VALUES
    ( RefIDDump, new.Dump_1, new.Dump_3, new.Dump_2, new.Dump_4, new.Dump_5, new.Dump_6, new.Dump_7, new.Dump_8, new.Dump_9);

END CASE;
END
```

Comment: Why the MS SQL Server tag?

Comment: Accident. Removed now.